# Kotlin compiler says getString() is nullable even though it has a default value

Tags: android, kotlin

My code:

```
var users: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
lateinit var players: ArrayList<Player>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val sharedPrefPlayers = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPrefPlayers?.all?.keys?.forEach {
        val filename = "player_$it"
        val playerSharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        players.add(Player(playerSharedPref!!.getString("name", ""), playerSharedPref.getInt("age", 0), playerSharedPref.getString("gender", "male")))
    }
    players = arrayListOf()
}
```

I'm getting a `Type Mismatch - Required: String, Found: String?` on my `getString()` call above. I'm not sure how the `String` is nullable as there is a default String backdrop of `""` if "name" is not found.

Also, the `getInt()` call doesn't have that error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), this is because `SharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue)` is nullable.

in other words, the `getString(String, String)` of `SharedPreferences` as follows.

```
@Nullable
String getString(String key, @Nullable String defValue);
```

So even you passed a non-null string, Kotlin still consider that `playerSharedPref!!.getString("name", "")` could be null.

You can overcome this issue by assuring that `playerSharedPref!!.getString("name", "")` to be non-null.

Solution:
put `!!` at the end of `playerSharedPref!!.getString("name", "")`, so the result will be `playerSharedPref!!.getString("name", "")!!`

Hope this helps!